# Android Jigsaw game - Native vs Phonegap

Tags: android, performance, cordova

I need to build a jigsaw game which will run only on android platform. I was thinking about using Phonegap(HTML5) to build the app, and then I heard that they don't give better performance than native apps. So, this game has high resolution graphics, meant to run on a large device, and is expected to give great performance in terms of speed. So, can you please give me a brief comparison between android native app and phonegap app considering the jigsaw game and suggest me what should i go for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to build on android platform only, I see no reason why you should choose html5 over native. Also, consider that Android [does not recommend using phonegap](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2013/06/donts-of-android-design.html) for a good responsive design. Not saying that phonegap is bad, it's just that you could make an app that is tailored to android users by going native.

Comment: the reason is i know html5 but not java. And one more thing i forgot to mention, it doesnt need to be responsive. it is meant to run on just one screen size(view-sonic or itouch)

Comment: The statement that "Android does not recommend using phonegap" seems to be a pretty biased opinion of one person who doesn't provide any facts or data to support his statement. There are an enormous amount of apps created with Phonegap/Cordova that perform great and look beautiful (see a sampling here: http://www.tmz.com/2013/06/21/waka-flocka-amanda-bynes-rap-album/). Sure, Facebook switched to native after failing with HTML5 app, but Sencha proved that they just authored the app wrong and ignored the needed architectural changes when moving from web app to hybrid app.